# How do I create an automatic break in long math expressions

Tags: equations, line-breaking

Is there a way to allow long math expressions to break automatically, whenever (and only) in situations where they extend beyond the body text of a document?

For example, I would like something like the following to break over two lines *if* (and only if) it finds itself in a narrow column of text (say, if `<class>` is `IEEEtran`), but otherwise remain on a single line (if, for example `<class>` is `article`), as long as it fits within a single (wider) column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\[ 
\hat{S}=\sum_{l\in\left\{ 1,\ldots L\right\} }\left[\bigl[1\!-\! f_{p}(l\!+\!1)\bigr]\;\overline{w}(l-1)\;\biggl[\,\prod_{i=0}^{l-1}\; f_{p}(i)\;\,\overline{\! N}(i)\biggr]\;\hat{H}_{S}(l-1)\right]
\]   
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the `breqn` package aims to do this...

Comment: @cmhughes: Is there an approach that avoids using an additional package (`breqn` sounds a bit disruptive)?

Comment: @cmhughes: It looks like I need to redefine `\[  to be `\begin{dmath}` to use `breqn`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you want do it globally? That would be quite interesting! If that's the way you want to go, perhaps a question edit is in order...

Comment: @cmhughes: Clarified, (I think).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Automatic line breaking for math expressions is **extremely difficult (algorithmically)**. It is much easier to use `breqn` rather than trying to implement that algorithm on your own.

Comment: @Aditya: Yes, but in order to do that I'll need a way to programmatically replace `\[..\]` with `dmath` environments.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: (Untested), but that is something as simple as `\let\[\dmath \let\]\enddmath`.

Comment: @Aditya: That fails, I can't redefine those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine some of the comments to the question, this answer uses the `breqn` package and redefines the `\[` and `\]` commands as `\begin{dmath}` and `\end{dmath}`, respectively.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{breqn}

\renewcommand\[{\begin{dmath}}
\renewcommand\]{\end{dmath}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\[
\hat{S}=\sum_{l\in\left\{ 1,\ldots L\right\} }\left[\bigl[1\!-\! f_{p}(l\!+\!1)\bigr]\;\overline{w}(l-1)\;\biggl[\,\prod_{i=0}^{l-1}\; f_{p}(i)\;\,\overline{\! N}(i)\biggr]\;\hat{H}_{S}(l-1)\right]
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```